# PHP error with my website page

Tags: php, syntax-error

I am having an issue with php on some of my pages. I don't know how to fix this error I am getting.

```
Warning: set_time_limit() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/sweetsun/public_html/products/coffee/rss.inc on line 8

Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /home/sweetsun/public_html/products/coffee/rss.inc on line 81

Warning: fopen(http://news.google.com/news?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rls=GGLG,GGLG:2005-22,GGLG:en&q=Coffee&output=rss) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /home/sweetsun/public_html/products/coffee/rss.inc on line 81
could not open XML input
```

I opened the file in Notepad ++ to fix the code, I tried setting the time_limit to 0 that didn't work.

The format should look like [this page](http://sweetsunrisemedia.com/products/coffee/index-2.php).

Comment: Your PHP configuration is blocking certain functionality of your page. You can try altering your php.ini by setting `allow_url_open` and `max_execution_time` (or do this in your php file using `ini_set`), but it's possible your host is blocking this on a server level. If it's not critical to your site, you can hide the warnings using `error_reporting(0);`

Comment: Thank you for your advice Jason, I don't see where an php.ini file to configure it is. I did not use php myadmin to set up the pages, I will check with my host to see if it is on their end.

Answer (score 0):

The server is configured so you are not allowed to call set_time_limit function ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions )

and you can't open file via network ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen )

You have to reconfigure the server or migrate to some server which allows this.